# Python: How to join files based on columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have to join 2 files based on common columns (year,month,day). Input files have header and output file will have the header as well.The 1st file has information on temperature as (example):

```
year month day min-temp mav-temp
2017 12    13  13       25
2017 12    16  25       32
2017 12    25  34       56
```

2nd file has information precipitation as (example)

```
year month day precipitation snow snow-cover
2018  7    6   0.00          0.0  0
2017  12   13  0.04          0.0  0
2017  12   16  0.4           0.04 1
```

My expected output should be (**ordered by date asynchronous , if no value found then blank**):

```
year month day min-temp mav-temp precipitation snow snow-cover
2017 12    13  13       25       0.04          0.0  0
2017 12    16  25       32       0.4           0.04 1
2017 12    25  34       56                 
2018  7    6                     0.00          0.0  0
```

May I get help on how to do that in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
new_df = (df1.merge(df2, on=['year','month','day'], how='outer')
          .sort_values(['year','month','day'])
          .fillna(''))

>>> new_df 
   year  month  day min-temp mav-temp precipitation  snow snow-cover
0  2017     12   13       13       25          0.04     0          0
1  2017     12   16       25       32           0.4  0.04          1
2  2017     12   25       34       56                               
3  2018      7    6                               0     0          0
```

Comment: When I will read the files as pandas.read_csv(...), how will that know what are the headers?

Comment: by default, pandas takes the first row as the header. see the header argument [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv) from pandas.